# Routing with parameters in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've got a results page for my website that outputs a list of users.

```
@extends('templates.default')

@section('content')
    <h3>Results for "{{ Request::input('query') }}"</h3>


    @if (!$users->count())
        <p>No results found, sorry.</p>
    @else

    <div class="resultRow">
        <div class="">
            @foreach ($users as $user)
                    @include('user/partials/userblock')
            @endforeach

        {!! $users->appends(Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
 @stop
```

with a fairly standard search controller:

```
class SearchController extends Controller {
public function getResults(Request $request) {
    $query = $request->input('query');

    $users = User::where(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)"), 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->where('role', '=', 2)
    ->orWhere('username', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->where('role', '=', 2)
    ->orWhere('profile_text', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->where('role', '=', 2)
    ->orWhere('keywords', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->where('role', '=', 2)
    ->orWhere('tagline', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->where('role', '=', 2)
    ->simplePaginate(1);


    return view('search.results')->with('users', $users);
 }
}
```

Now, this works fine and well. If I search for "Jack", I get all the Jacks.

What I want to know now is, would it be possible to have a route with a predefined parameter or query string?

For example, say, on my front page I had a link to all the plumbers in my users.

```
<a id="plumbers" href="{{ route('search.results')->withQueryOfPlumbers }}">Plumbers</a></li>
```

Would this be possible? Or should I be outputting my data another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just using GET parameters, the `route()` helper allows you to pass parameters as a second parameter such as: `route('search.results', ['user-type, => 'plumbers'])`

This will output: `http://www.example.com/search/results?user-type=plumbers`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column to your `User` called `profession`, then you'd do something like this:

```
$plumbers = User::where(['profession'=>'plumber', /*other WHERE options*/])->get();
```

This will return all of the `users` that are `plumbers`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hard coding the id and text of the a link, then you could just do

```
<a id="plumbers" href="{{ route('search.results') }}/plumbers">Plumbers</a>
```

And then match the keyword of plumbers in your routing table, see [Laravel docs on routing parameters for more info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-parameters).

Your route would look something like this:

```
Route::get('/search/{trade?}', ['uses' =>'SearchController@getResults', 'as' => 'search.results']);
```

You should be able to then inject the $trade variable into your controller. A small aside, I would avoid using raw queries in controllers as much as possible from a design and maintenance perspective and make a "search" helper function in your Eloquent model for users (See [Eloquent query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes)).